# How to display list of objects in a View for an MVC project

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, list

I have a method that will return a list of string objects. I would like to display those list of objects as checkboxes in the view.

```
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("AvailablePlans")]
        public ActionResult GetPlan()
        {
                List<Plans> plans = new();

        plans.Add(new Plans { PlanId = 1, PlanName = "Internet" });
        plans.Add(new Plans { PlanId = 2, PlanName = "TV & Streaming" });
        plans.Add(new Plans { PlanId = 3, PlanName = "Mobile" });
        plans.Add(new Plans { PlanId = 4, PlanName = "Home Security" });
        plans.Add(new Plans { PlanId = 5, PlanName = "Home Phone" });


            var plansAvailable = JsonSerializer.Serialize(plans);
            _logger.Log(LogLevel.Information, "Response-Body: {@Response-Body}", plansAvailable);


            return Ok(plans);
        }
```

I have tried the following inside of the view, but `plans` count is constantly 0 whenever I call it. Is there a specific way to display the list of objects as checkboxes?

```
@model PhoneNumberInput


<h2>Second page</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
 
    <input type="checkbox" id="@PlanService.API.Controllers.PlansController.plans[0]" name="PlanService.API.Controllers.PlanControllers.plans[1]" />
    <label for="PlanService.API.Controllers.PlanControllers.plans[1]"> @PlanService.API.Controllers.PlansController.plans[1] </label> <br />

    @Html.TextBoxFor(r => r.PhoneNumber)
    <input id="Button" type="submit" value="Next" />

    <p>  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(r => r.PhoneNumber) </p>

}
```

---

Update:

I currently have the following as so:

```
namespace Plan.API.Models
{
    public class ViewPhoneNumberInput
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "You did not enter your phone number! Please enter your phone number!")]
        public String PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public List<Plans> plans { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
namespace Plan.Api.Controllers
{

     public static List<Plans> plans = new();

     [HttpGet]
        [Route("AvailablePlans")]
        public ActionResult GetPlan()
        {

            var model = new ViewPhoneNumberInput();
            model.plans = new List<Plans>();

            model.plans.Add(new Plans { PlanId = 1, PlanName = "Internet" });
            model.plans.Add(new Plans { PlanId = 2, PlanName = "TV & Streaming" });
            model.plans.Add(new Plans { PlanId = 3, PlanName = "Mobile" });
            model.plans.Add(new Plans { PlanId = 4, PlanName = "Home Security" });
            model.plans.Add(new Plans { PlanId = 5, PlanName = "Home Phone" });


            var plansAvailable = JsonSerializer.Serialize(model.plans);
            _logger.Log(LogLevel.Information, "Response-Body: {@Response-Body}", plansAvailable);


            return Ok(model.plans);
        }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The checkbox usually accepts a bool value and I think your code is asp core.

But I will explain the procedure in asp mvc.

add ViewModelPhoneNumberInput class

```
public class ViewModelPhoneNumberInput
{
   public PhoneNumberInput phoneNumberInput   {get; set; }
   public List<Plans> plans {get; set; }
}
```

change action to :

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("AvailablePlans")]
public ActionResult GetPlan()
{
    var model = new ViewModelPhoneNumberInput();
    model.plans = new List<Plans>();

    plans.Add(new Plans { PlanId = 1, PlanName = "Internet" });
    plans.Add(new Plans { PlanId = 2, PlanName = "TV & Streaming" });
    plans.Add(new Plans { PlanId = 3, PlanName = "Mobile" });
    plans.Add(new Plans { PlanId = 4, PlanName = "Home Security" });
    plans.Add(new Plans { PlanId = 5, PlanName = "Home Phone" });
    var plansAvailable = JsonSerializer.Serialize(plans);
    _logger.Log(LogLevel.Information, "Response-Body: {@Response-Body}", plansAvailable);

    return View(model);
}
```

change view to :

```
@model yournamespace.ViewModelPhoneNumberInput
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    for(int i= 0;i < Model.plans.Count; i++)
    {
       <input type="checkbox" id="@Model.plans[i].PlanId" name="Model.plans[i].PlanId" />
       <label for="Model.plans[i].PlanId"> @Model.plans[i].PlanName </label> <br />
    }
    

    @Html.TextBoxFor(r => r.phoneNumberInput.PhoneNumber)
    <input id="Button" type="submit" value="Next" />
    <p>  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(r => r.phoneNumberInput.PhoneNumber) </p>
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! I see, so if my action controller is in a asp.net core web api project and the view is in the MVC project I would need to right click on my web api project and add reference for the mvc project that contains the ViewPhoneNumberInput model class in order to call it in the action controller, correct? If so I tried it but on the line `model.plans` it has a red line under `plans` saying "The type or namespace name `Plans` could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: My answer was somehow wrong, I corrected it. If you use asp mvc you do not need any reference

Comment: You must tell the controller the namespace where you added the model. with the key (ctrl +. ) Can add assembly reference.

Comment: Thank you! On my end in the for loop it says Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'List<Plans>'. Were you getting the same when you did `i < Model.plans`?

Comment: I had forgotten . Yes, it is correct to use Model.plans.Count

Comment: Awesome thank you! When debugging the for loop and hitting the `i < Model.plans.Count` it says `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` but I thought that was handled in the model class?

Comment: I removed the `PhoneNumberInput.cs` file from my models folder in the MVC project, and just created the same one but added `public List<Plans> plans {get; set;}` in that file. I created that in the API project. Then in the `SecIndex.cshtml` I did `@model myNamespace.PhoneNumberInput`. Just confused why its hits a null and says the object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: No, you should not delete the PhoneNumberInput class, it is needed. I need to see the SecIndex action.

Comment: Could that be the reason why when debugging `model`  in the action controller (api project) it says it is null at the `return Ok(model)`?

Comment: Also, if I have keep the PhoneNumberInput class in the MVC project, how can I reference that file in the API project if I already referenced the API project in the MVC in order to call the @model apiNamespace.ViewModelPhoneNumberInput? I tried adding it the same way I did to the other project but it says it will cause a circular dependency

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235659/discussion-between-markco-and-meysam-asadi).